# Trying to incorporate a timer in a game, with Visual Studio using C#

Tags: c#, xaml, timer, visual-studio-2015

I am new to C# development, but I am trying to write a game for my children which incorporates a timer.  I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 (Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3).  I am using the "Blank" template, and I am targeting Universal Windows, "Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393)".

On MainPage.xaml, I assumed I would be able to click on the Toolbox and select a "Timer" control, which would then appear in the code underneath, and which I would then be able to reference in MainPage.xaml.cs.

However, there is no "Timer" control available to select from the list of "All XAML Controls", and when I try to insert "using System.Timers" in MainPage.xaml.cs, it doesn't seem to recognise it.

All I need is for a timer to start "ticking" when the Start button is pressed, and to allow input for a fixed number of seconds before "timing out" and moving on to the next question.

Any pointers would be very gratefully received!

Comment: Quick Google search: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds like you are used to programming in the drag and drop interface of WinForms or VB6... To accomplish what you are describing you would need a button and an input control in your XAML and then the timer would reside in code-behind (or if you were following MVVM then it would live in your view model). A simple implementation of this could look like:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" x:Name="StartButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Start" Click="StartButton_Click" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="InputField" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ></TextBox>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" x:Name="StatusText" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Threading;
using Window.UI.Xaml;
using Window.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace UniversalTimerApp
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private Timer questionTimer;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.questionTimer = new Timer(this.EndOfTimer, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.questionTimer.Change(3000, Timeout.Infinite);
            this.StatusText.Text = "Timer Started!";
        }

        private async void EndOfTimer(object state)
        {
            await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                this.InputField.IsEnabled = false;
                this.StatusText.Text = "Timer Ended.";
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Sam.  I have tried what you suggest, but when I click on the Start button I get about 5 seconds delay and then the following error:

Comment: Thankyou Sam.  I have tried what you suggest, but when I click on the Start button I get about 5 seconds delay and then the following error: "Exception was  unhandled by user code.  An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in App4.exe but was not handled in user code.  Additional information: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800101E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))"

Comment: @Richard I have updated my answer to run the UI updating code in the EndOfTimer method on the UI thread so that you don't get that error. Please let me know if that works for you.